# How to create web api and consume from client application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am new in Asp.net Web API development. I want to develop Web API Restful service using Asp.Net Web API and Consume the client application. 
So, How to create Http verbs - GET,POST,PUT and DELETE method in Server and consume using httpclient in Asp.net application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Create a Asp.net Web API Application. Explain two application step by step.

1.Asp.Net Web API Creation
2.Consume Asp.Net Web API in Asp.Net MVC Application

**Asp.Net Web API Creation**

In visual studio - Create New Project -> Asp.Net Web Application -> Web API
[Change Authentication -> No Authentication] -> Click OK

Small code change in WebApiConfig.cs

By default

```
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

To add bellow code :

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ActionApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This Web Api application access Library function used by bellow files and its get data from database.

- SettingsBO
- ShipmentBO

I have develop the GET and POST method functionality bellow

```
namespace MyFirstWebAPI.Controllers
{

[RoutePrefix("api/Product")]
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetAllPorts")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Port>> GetAllPorts()
    {
        try
        {
            IEnumerable<Port> port = await SettingsBO.GetPortAsync();
            return port;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var err = ex.Message.ToString().Replace("\n", "N^^").Replace("\r", "R^^");
            var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(string.Format("Error Message = {0}", err)),
                ReasonPhrase = err
            };
            throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetShipmentDetails/{shipmentLId}/{orderid}")]
    public async Task<ShipmentLegViewModel> GetShipmentDetails(string shipmentLId, string orderid)
    {
        try
        {
            ShipmentLegViewModel shipmentDet = await ShipmentBO.GetSegmentLegDetailsAsync(shipmentLId, orderid);
            return shipmentDet;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var err = ex.Message.ToString().Replace("\n", "N^^").Replace("\r", "R^^");
            var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(string.Format("Error Message = {0}", err)),
                ReasonPhrase = err
            };
            throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("UpdatePort")]
    public async Task<string> UpdatePort(List<PortUpdate> port, string Id, string portStatusId)
    {
        try
        {
            return await SettingsBO.UpdateItemAsync(Id, port, portStatusId);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var err = ex.Message.ToString().Replace("\n", "N^^").Replace("\r", "R^^");
            var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(string.Format("Error Message = {0}", err)),
                ReasonPhrase = err
            };
            throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Above code is helps to create Asp.Net Web API Application. Buid and run the application using bellow structure.

URL : http://localhost:4314/api/Product/GetAllPorts

**2.Consume Asp.Net Web API in Asp.Net MVC Application**

I have create a Asp.Net MVC Application.

***You should add web api package for client application***

> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client

create a specific class [Webservice.cs] to access Web API data. Given bellow code

```
namespace WebAPI_Client.CNHService
{
public static class WebService<T> where T : class
{
    public static string appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceURL"];

    public static IEnumerable<T> GetDataFromService(string Method, string param = "")
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        try
        {
            var data = client.DownloadData(appSettings + Method + param);
            var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data);
            var obj = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(IEnumerable<T>));
            var result = obj.ReadObject(stream);
            IEnumerable<T> Ts = (IEnumerable<T>)result;
            return Ts;
        }
        catch (WebException wex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public static T GetDataFromService_SingleCollection(string Method, string param = "")
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new WebClient();
            var data = client.DownloadData(appSettings + Method + param);
            var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data);
            var obj = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            var result = obj.ReadObject(stream);
            T Ts = (T)result;
            return Ts;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }


    public static async Task<T> GetShipmentDetails(string shipmentLId,string orderid)
    {
        Stream stream = null;
        T Ts = null;
        string url = "http://localhost:4314/api/Product/GetShipmentDetails/5462f4e3e4b09e0d94f5c9a2/5462f4e2e4b09e0d94f5c9a1";
        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var data = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                    var stre = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data);
                    var obj1 = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(IEnumerable<T>));
                    var result = obj1.ReadObject(stre);
                    Ts = (T)result;
                }
                else
                {
                    stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                    var error = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
                return Ts;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return Ts;
    }

    public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetPorts()
    {
        Stream stream = null;
        IEnumerable<T> Ts = null;
        string url = "http://localhost:4314/api/Product/GetAllPorts";
        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var data = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                    var stre = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data);
                    var obj1 = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(IEnumerable<T>));
                    var result = obj1.ReadObject(stre);
                    Ts = (IEnumerable<T>)result;
                }
                else
                {
                    stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                    var error = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
                return Ts;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return Ts;
    }

    public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetDataFromService_Update(string Method, List<Port> portData, string param = "")
    {
        try
        {
            string requestUri = Method + param;
            string url = "http://localhost:4314/";
            IEnumerable<T> Ts = null;
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(requestUri, portData);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    var error = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }
            return Ts;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

}

*Controller code*

For GET and POST Method

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
         //GET Method      
         IEnumerable<Port> portq = await CNHService.WebService<Port>.GetPorts();
         //POST Method      
         List<Port> port = portq.ToList<Port>();
         IEnumerable<string> resUpdate = await CNHService.WebService<string>.GetDataFromService_Update("api/Product/UpdatePort", port, "?Id=5462f4d8e4b09e0d94f5c96f&portStatusId=5462f4d8e4b09e0d94f5c96c");
    }
}
```

Above code is working fine to get and post method.

This code is more help to your Web API application development

Comment: Thanks for your response.